# Twilio flow execution shows multiple errors

Tags: rest, api, twilio

I took this code directly from Twilio's website to use for triggering a flow i designed in studio to send an sms message. I would normally avoid asking such a question so quickly but we are hurriedly building this Twilio app to facilitate communication during a labor dispute and I think its capabilities will help us greatly.It isn't even close to working. Please help me get this simple thing operational on my windows machine using command prompt.

I spent three hours watching videos but have been unsuccessful.

```
curl -X POST "https://studio.twilio.com/v1/Flows/FWc786af1999122b6bfb9cd72ceb00b56c/Executions" \
--data-urlencode "To=+15712351969" \
--data-urlencode "From=+12028043219" \
-u "deleted for privacy:deleted for privacy"
```

## See resulting errors from CMD

```
C:\Users\Mark>curl -X POST "https://studio.twilio.com/v1/Flows/FWc786af1999122b6bfb9cd72ceb00b56c/Executions" \
{"code": 20003, "detail": "Your AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect.", "message": "Authentication Error - No credentials provided", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003", "status": 401}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \

C:\Users\Mark>--data-urlencode "To=+15712351969" \
'--data-urlencode' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Mark>--data-urlencode "From=+12028043219" \
'--data-urlencode' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like, from your error, that the backslashes aren't continuing the line for you.

For a start, I'd try running the command all on one line in the terminal. Like:

```
curl -X POST "https://studio.twilio.com/v1/Flows/FWc786af1999122b6bfb9cd72ceb00b56c/Executions" --data-urlencode "To=+15712351969" --data-urlencode "From=+12028043219" -u "deleted for privacy:deleted for privacy"
```

See how that goes and let me know if it helps.

Comment: No worries,  I'm glad you got it sorted!